# Selecting information_schema.columns is only returning the first 1025 characters. Why?

Tags: mysql, dynamic, schema

When I run the query below, I only get half my column names surrounded by single quotes(which was exactly 1025 characters). I using Sequel Pro's query execution window. I have tried to type cast @columnNames. No luck.

```
select group_concat(concat("'",column_name, "'")) into @columnNames 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name=@tableName;
```

Because I have to know..... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) server variable, which by default is 1024, prior to executing your query.

> **group_concat_max_len**
>   The maximum permitted result length in bytes for the GROUP_CONCAT() function.
>   The default is 1024.

```sql
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; -- or any other appropriate value
```

Comment: Ha, I thought it was something to do with the session var implicitly changing data types to something like varchar(1025). I should have seen this in the documentation. :-/ I appreciate the answer(plus 1). :)~